# EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://localhost:8000/", facing an error while connecting local dynamodb

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-local

I am trying to establish a connection between the locally created lambda function and local dynamodb. I set up both lambda and dynamodb locally and tried to create table in the dynamodb but facing an error. Here is my script to create a table in dynamodb through local lambda [image: table creation script and connection with dynamodb local]

Thus far, everything is going fine but when I try to execute the code, it throws an error that you can examine [image: here]

On the other hand, the local dynamodb is also working fine that you can see [image: here]

I don't know where I am doing wrong, i also have configured aws secrect access key, id, and region. Kindly help me, I would really appreciate that.

Comment: How are you trying to connect them? Are we talking two docker containers or just local installs in the OS?

Comment: without docker, loca installation